# fbDidLogin not called and handleURL not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

I am using Facebook Connect with my app. Everything is set up, all the code WAS working. Around yesterday, I could login with my app, then post stuff and other functions. I don't recall making any real changes. Now, as usual, whenever I press login and it goes to a Safari page where I have to confirm that I want to use this app and it says who I am logging in as. If I press ok it goes back to the app. During this whole process, in the app, Facebook never logs in. REMEMBER: JUST YESTERDAY THIS WORKS, I DONT RECALL MAKING ANY CHANGES! Here is how the connection starts:

```
-(IBAction)connectToFacebook {

[loginButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LoginWithFacebookPressed@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"387500177929927" andDelegate:self];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}    
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(makeVisibleButtons) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
[timer setAccessibilityHint:@"timer"];
}

 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
   // JUST SO THAT HANDLE URL CAN GET CALLED

return YES;


}
```

So I press a button to call this IBAction. The NSTimer is not related, its just for  the appearance of some buttons. Now, these two methods never get called (when I log it):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url 
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation { 
ConnectToFB *connect = [[ConnectToFB alloc] init];
return [connect.facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
NSLog(@"url");
[connect release];
 }

- (void)fbDidLogin {

NSLog(@"log in");

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];    
 }
```

The app id is up to date and my url schemes in info plist is also up to date. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your application is not getting any access_token for login into facebook. It might be giving you null.

If it's the problem.Then in hook into FBDialog and

change this:

```
- (NSString *) getStringFromUrl: (NSString*) url needle:(NSString *) needle {
NSString * str = nil;
NSRange start = [url rangeOfString:needle];
if (start.location != NSNotFound) {
    // confirm that the parameter is not a partial name match
    unichar c = '?';
    if (start.location != 0) {
        c = [url characterAtIndex:start.location - 1];
    }
    if (c == '?' || c == '&') {        
        NSRange end = [[url substringFromIndex:start.location+start.length] rangeOfString:@"&"];
        NSUInteger offset = start.location+start.length;
        str = end.location == NSNotFound ?
            [url substringFromIndex:offset] : 
            [url substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(offset, end.location)];
        str = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
}    
return str;
}
```

with this:

```
- (NSString *) getStringFromUrl: (NSString*) url needle:(NSString *) needle {
NSString * str = nil;
NSRange start = [url rangeOfString:needle];
if (start.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSRange end = [[url substringFromIndex:start.location+start.length] rangeOfString:@"&"];
    NSUInteger offset = start.location+start.length;
    str = end.location == NSNotFound
    ? [url substringFromIndex:offset]
    : [url substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(offset, end.location)];
    str = [str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

return str;
}
```

It might solve your problem.

Comment: I never implemented that method. I added it in but it is still not working

Comment: have you got access token, while call back from safari?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by that, my app does direct to safari and when the user presses ok in safari Facebook dialog it goes back to the app. What do you mean by "have you got access token" @Sunny